# yaml file error java_opts

Tags: docker

java_opts: ["-Xmx512m","-Xms256m"] this simple yaml syntax giving error.

Error
message:
      - 'Unrecognized field "java_opts" (class com.bb.bp.assembly.PortDefiniti
on)

anyone have idea?

Comment: What's the service you're trying to start? (put the full service section of your compose file here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable multiple ways:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Xms256m"
CMD printenv JAVA_OPTS
```

Build & run:

```
docker build -t java-opts-image .
docker run --rm --name java-opts-container java-opts
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
test:
 image: ubuntu
 environment: 
    - JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Xms256m"
 command: printenv JAVA_OPTS
```

Build & run:

```
docker-compose up
```

**docker run**

```
docker run --rm --name java-opts-container --env JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Xms256m" ubuntu:latest printenv JAVA_OPTS
```

Comment: why are we adding  - JAVA_OPTS " - " before the java_opts ? just doubt

Comment: Is related to how you declare a list in yaml